# Jasper/iReport - Extra long text does not display properly in excel export

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I have a field with excessively long text. When I export the jasper report as xls, the row height does not extend to display the entire content.

Althought the text is present in the cell, the row height needs to be manually increased to see the entire content.

I am using Jasper report version 6.10 and have set the following properties

```
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.show.gridlines" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet" value="false"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.white.page.background" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.fit.width" value="1"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.wrap.text" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.print.page.top.margin" value="40"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.print.page.bottom.margin" value="40"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.print.page.left.margin" value="36"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.print.page.right.margin" value="36"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.freeze.row" value="2"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.page.height" value="false"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.fit.height" value="0"/>
```

Please suggest how I can fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use following properties in Report Element

```
<staticText>
    <reportElement x="0" y="100" width="100" height="20">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column" value="true"/>
    </reportElement>
    <textElement/>
    <text>
        <![CDATA[Your Static Text]]>
    </text>
</staticText>
```

Also I'd recommend you to try using net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.column.width property, which is more useful. Reference: http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html

Comment: Hi Sagar, I have added these properties as well on the reportElement. However, the behaviour is exactly the same as explained above. The text is present in the cell, however, the cell height is not adjusted to display the entire content.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of excel